# oferta de algo vs oferta para algo

Tags: preposiciones

Usually I translate "an offer of something to someone" to Spanish as "una oferta de algo a alguien", eg una oferta de trabajo a un candidato". However, I have recently heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series:

> Rechazaron nuestra oferta para la amnistía

Is there any difference in meaning between "oferta de algo" and "oferta para algo"? Is the latter usual in all Spanish speaking countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"oferta de algo" is used when "algo" is the thing being offered.

"oferta para algo" is used to introduce the field where the offer was, is, or will be made.

In:

- Rechazaron nuestra oferta **de** amnistía.

the idea is that they refused the offer of an amnesty: they don't want the amnesty.

In:

- Rechazaron nuestra oferta **para** la amnistía.

both parties had agreed on the idea of an amnesty but not on its terms. Therefore, they refused our terms to declare an amnesty, but not the amnesty itself. We might modify the terms and they might accept them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tricky. I thought that "rechazaron la amnistía" would be used to express the first meaning.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista, no es lo mismo.